# Ruby conditional issue?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def name_of_client
  puts "Hello sir/madam; please enter your name: "
  name = gets.chomp.upcase
  puts "Welcome to the Great Bank, #{name}. Would you like to enter your seriously insecure account? (Y/N)"
end

def get_response
  answer = gets
  if answer == "Y" || answer == "y"
    puts 'Sure thing... '
  elsif answer == "N" || answer== "n"
    puts "Logging you out now. "
  end
end

name_of_client
get_response
```

Why are the strings not printed when I type `"Y"` or `"N"`?

Comment: `answer = gets.chomp`—`gets` returns the input _including the EOL separator_.

Comment: @Amir you have already used `gets.chomp` in `name_of_client`, so you are obviously aware of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gets` adds a new line to the `answer` variable. use `gets.chomp` or `gets.strip` instead. In future, I would recommend using the pry gem as shown below which pauses execution just like debugger does in javascript. To install `pry` open your terminal window (assuming you're running linux or macOS) and run `gem install pry`. You can then use it as shown below.

```
require "pry"

def get_response
  answer = gets.strip
  binding.pry
  if answer == "Y" || answer == "y"
      puts 'Sure thing... '
    elsif answer == "N" || answer== "n"
      puts "Logging you out now. "

  end
end

get_response
```